# Highcharts y-axis Ceiling not being respected

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with Highcharts where the Ceiling of one of my two y-axes is not being respected.

Y-axis "1" represents percentage values, so has a Floor of 0 and a Ceiling of 100.

Y-axis "2" represents monetary values, so has a Floor of 0 and a Ceiling of *null*.

For some reason, the labels for y-axis "1" go up to 150.

If I change the corresponding series data so that the value 0 is changed to 20, the problem seems to go away and the labels stop at 100 as they should.

```
var dataX = [0, 67,  43, 100, 100, 80];
var dataY = [950, 900, 807, 650, 600, 450];

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        series: [{
            name: 'Series 1',
            data: dataX,
            yAxis: 0},
        {
            name: 'Series 2',
            data: dataY,
            yAxis: 1}],
        yAxis: [{
                floor: 0,
                ceiling: 100,
                title: {
                    text: '1'
                },
            },
            {
                floor: 0,
                ceiling: null,
                title: {
                    text: '2'
                },

                opposite: true}]});});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2bzew/2/

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create your own `tickPositioner`, or set directly `tickPositions`: http://jsfiddle.net/2bzew/4/

See docs and more examples:

- [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner)
- [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions)

Comment: It seems as though this is the route I will have to go down. It is unfortunate that they have only made it this way round. Fundamentally the it seems to be flawed, as a Ceiling should be a Ceiling and other things should be adjusted by the Highcharts component to ensure that this is the case. However, as this doesn't appear to be what is happening, it would be good at least if it was possible to specify the number of ticks that you want to appear and let it calculate based on that, rather than expecting us to calculate everything.

Comment: Just `alignTicks` has higher priority than any other options, to make chart more friendly for user. Of course, someone may need another solution, that's why it's possible to write specific `tickPositioner` - to get better control of a chart. If you have any problems with `tickPositioner` let me know, I'll help you. It's quite easy, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The tickPositioner is far from ideal for me, but it does seem like the best of a bad bunch of options.

Comment: Almost 5 years later after the original question I have the same problem with dual axes, where one uses way too high max value. This answer is poor - it doesn't solve the problem - just points to a workaround that's not really that great either. What if the datasets for both y-axes are dynamic and you need to align ticks for both axes as not to clutter the chart. If you use tickPositions, you end up having to compute the ticks for both axes so their respective 25%, 50%, 75% (or more if you fancy more ticks) need to align perfectly. By doing that you end up with weird nums like 27.5 or 237.5

Comment: @codeepic - that's correct. It's a general problem with aligning ticks between multiple axes. Either you will have not-so-nice numbers on yAxis, or you increase the max value to get rounded ticks. For example try to find nice five ticks for 0-100 (0-25-50-75-100) and 0-15(0-3.75-7.5-11.25-15). It's easier to rescale 0-15 -> 0-20 and render 0-5-10-15-20 (rounded numbers). Note that number of ticks, as OP asked, is added to the core to help solve the issue: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickAmount and you have access to calculated `ticks` in `tickPositioner`.

Comment: Ok thanks Paweł. I am fine with that, but our designer doesn't like the max y axis to jump up to almost double the max dataset value. When that happens after user interacted with filters, the line drops down on the chart. The nums are more or less the same but without checking the y axis it looks like there is a huge drop.

Comment: Thanks! This can be a bug, I suggest to create a jsFiddle demo and contact Highcharts support :) Or maybe you use old version of Highcharts?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, but I found that using the following solves the issue:

```
        maxPadding: 0,
        minPadding: 0,
```

The default for these values are both 0.05 so that will be added to your data and cause highstock to make the y axis bigger than intended.  Zeroing them out seems to fix the problem for me.

I also recommend to set the following so that maximum value still has a label:

```
        showLastLabel: true,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M4bVz/

Comment: This solved it for me too. My area chart values were in the range 0-100, but the padding went from -50 to 150.

Answer (score 5):

From [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks):

> When using multiple axis, the ticks of two or more opposite axes will automatically be aligned by adding ticks to the axis or axes with the least ticks. This can be prevented by setting alignTicks to false. If the grid lines look messy, it's a good idea to hide them for the secondary axis by setting gridLineWidth to 0. Defaults to true.

I have updated your fiddle with these corrections.

```
chart: {
        alignTicks: false
    },
...
yAxis: [{
            ...
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2bzew/3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

However, while this explains the behaviour to some extent, it doesn't explain why -- given that I have told one of the axes that it doesn't have a Ceiling -- it can't just use numbers that can match up. 

It could even use decimals if it was having difficulties with divisibility! Fundamentally it seem to be having a problem because it wants to have five stops for axis "1" (0,25,50,75,100) and four for axis "2" (400,600,800,1000). Who told it that these stops were necessary, and can it not be told otherwise?

Is there really nothing else that can be done?

Comment: It is default behvaioru so you need alignTicks as false, accoridng to @Sualkcin. You can also prepare your own tickPositioner function: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner