# Highcharts adding additional series and axis breaks existing yAxis min/max

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the following fiddle (based on a Highcharts example), the first series shows correctly, taking up the entire height of the chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/markalroberts/h9j53yk4/4/

However, when you click the button to add a series, the existing series' scale is recalculated (not what I want).

The code I use to add the axis/series/data:

```
chart.addSeries({
        type: 'line',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
    })
```

How can the existing series/yAxis combo be set to remain as it was originally and just have the new series plotted ontop (also scaled to use the entire height of the chart)

**Update**

As per Mike's answer, what I had to do was simply:

```
alignTicks: false
```

Comment: I think that your main problem is marginTop parameter. If you will set it to some value greater than 0 - for example 10, the problem should not exist anymore. Right now your last tick is on the start of your chart so you are seeing only part of this tick. The reason for updating this extremes is that your new yAxis ticks and your previous yAxis ticks should be on the same y positions.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński - did you try this in the fiddle? I just tried it and it makes no difference setting the marginTop to 10.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to make it clearer what I want to achieve.... and basing my example the example from the Highcharts website.

Comment: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h9j53yk4/5/ You can also use tickAmount to have the same number of ticks: http://jsfiddle.net/h9j53yk4/12/ I hope it will help you with your problem.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński ok! so the tickAmount setting starts to do what I want (in that it doesn't change the first series when the second is added), however it no longer calculates the max properly, nor does it honour the max if I set one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with multiple axes can be tricky. I found the answer by **kjfagan** in this Stack Overflow question helpful for your situation: [Highcharts y-axis Ceiling not being respected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545641/highcharts-y-axis-ceiling-not-being-respected).

What I did in your fiddle was first set only the initial y-axis and give it the `minPadding: 0` and `maxPadding: 0` attributes as per kjfagan's answer:

```
yAxis: [{ 
    visible: true, 
    startOnTick: false, 
    endOnTick: false, 
    maxPadding: 0, 
    minPadding: 0
}],
```

Next, in your buttion, event, I set the full set of attributes for the new axis here, including the `minPadding` and `maxPadding` attributes:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    c.addAxis({ 
        visible: true, 
        startOnTick: false, 
        endOnTick: false, 
        maxPadding: 0, 
        minPadding: 0, 
        opposite: true });
    c.addSeries({yAxis:1})
    c.xAxis[0].series[1].setData(j.Lines[1].Data);
});
```

Lastly, as **Grzegorz Blachliński** thoughtfully suggested, I increased your `marginTop` for the chart itself.

In addition, I added `alignTicks: false` to prevent the chart from automatically adjusting the axes to one another's values, which can lead to some wonky or unexpected behavior, depending on what you're plotting.

```
chart: {
    marginTop: 20,
    alignTicks: false
},
```

Here's the modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/h9j53yk4/9/

Please note that clicking the button more than once will add multiple instances of the new axis, which will appear as duplicate axis labels. You also had `yAxis` declared more than once in the chart options of your original fiddle; I removed the extra option.

One last thing: you'll notice the gridlines from both axes don't quite line up. The answer from **Sualkcin** in the question I cited above has information on how to handle that (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23549591/2596103).

I hope this information is helpful for you.

Comment: Hey - thanks a lot for the answer, but I think I probably didn't make myself clear enough - can you look at my updated fiddle as above? I simply want that the first series *doesn't* change when I add the second... I don't see why it should as the second is on it's own axis, so it shouldn't affect the first, but it the first is drawn when a different min/max

Comment: @Kram I looked at the updated fiddle in your question. So, you don't want the chart to scale when adding the second series, giving the illusion that the line is "shrinking," is that correct?

Comment: Yes :) precisely. Sorry I wasn't clear enough... Grzegorz Blachliński mentioned the tickAmount is his comment above, which helps  - but as I replied, it now doesn't calculate the min/max properly nor does it honour the min/max if I set it explicitly

Comment: @Kram If you set `alignTicks: false` in your `chart` attribute, that should resolve that issue (see your updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/h9j53yk4/13/). I've found dual axis charts can be quite tricky to manage around min/max values. That attribute helps it better obey your requirements.

Comment: Excellent! That's what I wanted.... you are correct that multiple axis are rather confusing!!! Are you able to add this comment to your answer so I can mark it as the accepted one? Thanks :)

Comment: @Kram I'm very glad this was all useful for you. I've updated my answer per your request. Please let me know if there's anything else you need!