# Optimise Tick Positions To Minimise Wasted Space At Top Of Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If you run the snippet below, you will notice that in the first chart, there is a lot of space that is wasted at the top of a chart. The same chart at a different element height makes better use of the space.

How can I get Highcharts to optimise the `tickPositions` to reduce this wasted space?

I've tried to tweak the following Highcharts properties:

- `Ceiling`
- `Floor`
- `Min`
- `Max`

to no avail.

As a sidenote, this issue started affecting us on upgrading from v3 to v4 (latest)

```js
var model1 = {
  "chart": {},
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": ["2033", "2034", "2035", "2036", "2037", "2038", "2039", "2040", "2041", "2042", "2043", "2044", "2045", "2046", "2047"]
  },
  "yAxis": [{}, {
    "opposite": true,
  }],
  "series": [{
    "data": [0, 0, 0, 0.210042, 0.310498, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.305934, 0],
    "yAxis": 0
  }, {
    "data": [0, 0, 0, 9.652964, 13.575342, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.123286, 12.757988, 0],
    "yAxis": 1
  }],
};


$(function() {
  $('#container1').highcharts(model1);
  $('#container2').highcharts(model1);
});

//function increaseHeight(){
//$('#container1').height(400);
//console.log("Now resize the window to see the chart change");
//}
```

```css
#container1 {
  height: 300px;
}
#container2 {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<!-- button onclick="increaseHeight()">Resize Chart 1</button -->
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

Comment: I think that you should be able to use min and max with startOnTick and endOnTick parameters to achieve your goal. It should be also possible to use tickPositions for manually setting the positions of your ticks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having such trouble with this particular chart is due to how Highcharts handles dual axes. They can be tricky to work with, and attributes that would normally work, such as `ceiling`, `min`, `max`, etc. don't work as they do with single axis charts.

[I posted an answer a few weeks back to a similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304644/highcharts-adding-additional-series-and-axis-breaks-existing-yaxis-min-max/38305428#38305428) and applied a few of the ideas to your code snippet (see below).

```js
var model1 = {
  "chart": {},
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": ["2033", "2034", "2035", "2036", "2037", "2038", "2039", "2040", "2041", "2042", "2043", "2044", "2045", "2046", "2047"]
  },
  "yAxis": [{
    "startOnTick": false, 
    "endOnTick": false, 
    "maxPadding": 0, 
    "minPadding": 0
  }, {
    "opposite": true,
    "startOnTick": false, 
    "endOnTick": false, 
    "maxPadding": 0, 
    "minPadding": 0
  }],
  "series": [{
    "data": [0, 0, 0, 0.210042, 0.310498, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.328766, 0.305934, 0],
    "yAxis": 0
  }, {
    "data": [0, 0, 0, 9.652964, 13.575342, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.328766, 14.123286, 12.757988, 0],
    "yAxis": 1
  }],
};


$(function() {
  $('#container1').highcharts(model1);
  $('#container2').highcharts(model1);
});

//function increaseHeight(){
//$('#container1').height(400);
//console.log("Now resize the window to see the chart change");
//}
```

```css
#container1 {
  height: 300px;
}
#container2 {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<!-- button onclick="increaseHeight()">Resize Chart 1</button -->
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

As you can see, the "wasted space" you reported is gone. Note, however, that the relative position of both series does differ between different container heights. This is due to how Highcharts is calculating the intervals on each individual axis and plotting them against one another.

In my other answer, I suggested `alignTicks: false` for the `chart` attribute, but that gets a bit messy for your example. Also, setting an explicit `tickInterval` for the first (lighter-colored) series results in the same odd offset of gridlines.

So long as you don't have any objection to the disparity between the series positions, this should hopefully be useful for you.