# Highcharts: y-Axis last tick exceeds ceiling

Tags: javascript, highcharts

similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545641/highcharts-y-axis-ceiling-not-being-respected), I have a Highcharts spline chart with two y-Axis, the first representing a percentage, having floor and ceiling set at 0 and 100, and the second one an unknown numeric value. Setting the chart height to 200 results in the y-Axis showing 105 as last tick.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            alignTicks: false,
            height: 200
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Y axis exceeds `ceiling` value'
        },
        xAxis: {
            showFirstLabel: true,
            showLastLabel: true,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage'
            },
            floor: 0,
            ceiling: 100,
            //,
            //tickPositioner: function () {
            //      alert(this.tickPositions[this.tickPositions.length-1]);    
            //}
        },{
            title: {
                text: 'Number'
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: true
        }],
        series: [{
            data: [86, 89, 91, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97]
        }, {
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [685, 676, 651, 649, 649, 649, 649, 649, 649, 649, 649, 649]        
        }]
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxjfwm4g/2/)

I tried setting minPadding and maxPadding, but that doesn't work. I also tried setting my own tick positions using tickPoisitioner function, but the weird thing here is that the last tick position seems to be 100 (see commented code) but is shown as 105 anyway... Setting startOnTick to false does seem to help setting the last tick right, but that does not quite fit my requirements as I want the labels shown at first and last positions on the axis.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about using min and max parameters? http://jsfiddle.net/dxjfwm4g/3/

Comment: I did, but I don't want the first axis to show the complete range from 0 to 100 but to scale dynamically instead. But I guess, with my second axis showing numeric values and scaling differently anyway, I might just go with it...